# Microsoft Graph API: Get all meeting requests from inbox

Tags: outlook, office365, microsoft-graph-api

I am trying to get all Meeting requests from my Inbox via Microsoft graph api.
By this call i get all e-mails in the Inbox:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/mailFolders/inbox/messages
```

Now i am trying to filter only the Meeting requests

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/mailFolders/inbox/messages?$filter=meetingMessageType eq meetingRequest
```

But this Returns

```
Could not find a property named 'meetingMessageType' on type 'Microsoft.OutlookServices.Message'.
```

How can i get all unanswered Meeting requests in a users Inbox?
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use `microsoft.graph.eventMessage/meetingMessageType` instead of  `meetingMessageType`

`https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/mailFolders/inbox/messages?$filter=microsoft.graph.eventMessage/meetingMessageType eq 'meetingAccepted'`